# Encoding gone Wrong (PHP => JSON => Android)

Tags: php, android, json, encoding

The following problem occurs when I output something with PHP in JSON format and read it in my Android:

I have an & symbol in a string that occurs in the JSON code which isn't really displayed correctly. I'm sure it occurs with other symbols too but I haven't tested that.

I tried the following:

Raw "&" symbol:

```
Browser reads &, Android reads &#038;
```

htmlentities("&"):

```
Browser reads &#038;, Android reads &amp;#038;
```

htmlspecialchars("&"):

```
Browser reads &#038;, Android reads &amp;#038;
```

html_entity_decode("&"):

```
Browser reads &, Android reads &
```

The last one is the desired result, but it's just wrong to decode something before it's even encoded.. What am I doing wrong??

PS: The content is outputted in UTF-8, not sure what json_encode does with it, and read in UTF-8.

Comment: Maybe you should check the encoding set in Android. PHP's json_encode works only with UTF-8 encoded data.

Comment: I have confirmed everything is UTF-8 encoded already. I told Android to read it in UTF8 format, and my string in PHP is UTF-8. I also tried utf8_encode and alternatives.

Comment: Also check the encoding of the php file.

Comment: Okay, so I just placed header('Content-type: application/json'); at the top of the file. Now the browser output is exactly the same as Android, so that's one thing. Now I still have to use html_entity_decode before json_encode, otherwise I will still see &#038;

Comment: Did you also try changing the encoding of the php file which is returning the json string. According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php your files could be encoded as ISO-8859-1.